# Model not capturing dynamic input fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view model ***InvoiceViewModel*** and inside the ***InvoiceViewModel*** I have a property Items which is type list.

```
public class InvoiceViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public List<ItemsViewModel> Items { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The ***ItemsViewModel*** model looks like this

```
public class ItemsViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

The following fields get added into the HTML using jQuery dynamically

```
<tr id="InvoiceLine-606818967">
    <td class="text-left line-description">
        <textarea name="Items[].Name" id="line-description-606818967" class="band autogrow" rows="1"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right line-unit-cost">
        <input type="number" name="Items[].UnitPrice" placeholder="0.00" min="0.00" step="0.01">
    </td>
    <td class="text-right line-quantity">
        <input type="number" name="Items[].Quantity" placeholder="0">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="InvoiceLine-2196849859">
    <td class="text-left line-description">
        <textarea name="Items[].Name" id="line-description-2196849859" class="band autogrow" rows="1"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right line-unit-cost">
        <input type="number" name="Items[].UnitPrice" placeholder="0.00" min="0.00" step="0.01">
    </td>
    <td class="text-right line-quantity">
        <input type="number" name="Items[].Quantity" placeholder="0">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="InvoiceLine-7114958211">
    <td class="text-left line-description">
        <textarea name="Items[].Name" id="line-description-7114958211" class="band autogrow" rows="1"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right line-unit-cost">
        <input type="number" name="Items[].UnitPrice" placeholder="0.00" min="0.00" step="0.01">
    </td>
    <td class="text-right line-quantity">
        <input type="number" name="Items[].Quantity" placeholder="0">
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the form is submitted, the following is what I see during debugging of the ***InvoiceViewModel***

[image]

Please advise what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You say fields are dynamically added, do you specify the index for each item on the `name` of the input? It should be something like `name="Items[0].Name"`.

Comment: @colinD I didn't specify the index like `Items[0].Name` however I did something like `Items[].Name`

Comment: Yes, see the link. You need to specify the indexes. Actually a better way to do that using editor templates is described in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know your error message but maybe you can write `Items[iterationIndex].Quantity` or `item.Quantity` etc. Probably when submit your form, model not know which index is mine

Comment: Hello, I have edited my question with the image of the property values in the model. Please see if you can help.